# Passing a second variable to gawk in this Bash shell script is failing

Tags: bash, shell-script, awk

I want to pass two variables to my AWK script from my shell script.

```
#!/bin/bash

HeaderSize=$(grep -n "# end header data" input.list | tr ":" "\n" | head -n 1)
RecordSize=$(grep -n "# Number of unique" input.list | tr ":" "\n" | tail -n 1 | sed 's/,//g')

echo $HeaderSize
echo $RecordSize

head -n $HeaderSize input.list > temp.list

./parse.awk -v headersize=$HeaderSize -v recordsize=$RecordSize < input.list >> temp.list
```

File *parse.awk* looks something like this:

```
#!/bin/gawk -f

BEGIN {
    curline=1;
    excludeline=0;
    newrecordsize=0;
}
{
    if (curline < $headersize) {
        curline++;
    } else {
        if (($2 !~ /test1/) && ($2 !~ /test2/) && ($2 !~ /test3/)) {
            print $0;
        } else {
            excludeline++;
        }
    }
}
END {
    print "#", excludeline, "lines excluded";
    newrecordsize = recordsize - excludeline;
    printf "# Number of unique items after exclusions: %'d\n", newrecordsize;
}
```

So I just wanted to copy the header directly over, then do some exclude some of the data.

When I run the Bash file I get an error on the gawk execution:

```
38
94108
gawk: ./parse.awk:6: fatal: cannot open file `94108' for reading (No such file or directory)
```

94108 is the value for RecordSize or the second variable I'm trying to pass.

How can I fix this error?

**Edit**:
The answer is found below has to do with double quotes on the variables, which apparently I should be doing everywhere. Here are my current script which works fine.

```
#!/bin/bash

HeaderSize=$(grep -n "# end header data" input.list | tr ":" "\n" | head -n 1)
RecordSize=$(grep -n "# Number of unique" input.list | tr ":" "\n" | tail -n 1 | sed 's/,//g')

echo "$HeaderSize"
echo "$RecordSize"

head -n "$HeaderSize" input.list > temp.list

./parse.awk -v "headersize=$HeaderSize" -v "recordsize=$RecordSize" < input.list >> temp.list
```

I also cleaned up the awk script

```
#!/bin/gawk -f

BEGIN {
    excludeline=0;
    newrecordsize=0;
}

NR > headersize {
    if (($2 !~ /test1/) && ($2 !~ /test2/) && ($2 !~ /test3/)) {
        print $0;
    } else {
        excludeline++;
    }
}
END {
    print "#", excludeline, "lines excluded";
    newrecordsize = recordsize - excludeline;
    printf "# Number of unique domains after exclusions: %'d\n", newrecordsize; 
}
```

Comment: You are correctly passing the two values to your `gawk` script.  Something else is at play as your scripts run without error for me.

Comment: Copy/paste your shell script into http://shellcheck.net, fix the issues it will  tell you about, and then [edit] your question to show the corrected script if you still have a problem or, more likely, delete the question if you don't.

Comment: @fpmurphy it runs in bash fine but doesn't run in script. The issue has to do with putting things in quotes as per the answer below. shellcheck.net popped this up as a suggestion.

Comment: @EdMorton, thanks, I will be using that going forward.

Comment: You're welcome. FYI although putting the quotes around the whole assignment statement, `"recordsize=$RecordSize"`, won't do any harm, just putting the quotes around the value in  the statement is far more common syntax - `recordsize="$RecordSize"`.

Comment: @EdMorton So basically only quote each variable that I wish to call?

Comment: @misosoup7 the rule is simple - **always** quote shell variables unless you have a specific **need** not to. See https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I suspect there’s whitespace at the start of `$RecordSize`; quote your variables:

```
echo "$HeaderSize"
echo "$RecordSize"

./parse.awk -v "headersize=$HeaderSize" -v "recordsize=$RecordSize" < input.list >> temp.list
```

Comment: Also note probable incorrect use of `awk` variable `headersize` in their code (and possible also numerous other improvements that could be made).